# Doxygen packed definition

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to document a packed type with Doxygen but I can't figure it out : I don't have the description of each item, do you have an idea of how can I do this ? In the final output, I just have my @brief & detailled description..

```
/**
 * @typedef Pack
 * 
 * @brief Description
 * Detailled description
 *
 */

typedef enum
    __packed
    {
    A = 0,  //!< Description 1
    B = 1, //!< Description 2
    C = 2 //!< Description 3
    }Pack, *PPack;
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please have a look at the manual at Preprocessing, here an example is given regarding __dllspec and __attribute__ but I think this applies to __packed as well.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of @albert is correct but probably a bit short.
For your comfort I state the information form the Doxygen manual that Albert refers to.

To make doxygen understand the **__packed** keyword you have to adjust your doxygen configuration file like this:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION      = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF   = YES
PREDEFINED           = __packed
```

Here you find more information: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html